# Get values from deeply nested array of object using array.reduce

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract values from an array of objects that are deeply nested. Below are the data and anticipated results. I've already produced the necessary results. If I can do it using an array, it would be great. Trying to learn a better way to achieve this and make my code look better

```
const questionTree=[
    {
        "question_num": 20008000,
        "parent_num": 20000000,
        "order_num": 175,
        "control_type": "S",
        "question": "PACL",
        "mask": null,
        "keyword": null,
        "description": null,
        "enable": null,
        "required": null,
        "required1": null,
        "default_value": null,
        "negative_value": null,
        "summary_string": null,
        "insert_break": null,
        "req_children_num": null,
        "urgent": null,
        "validate_expr": null,
        "validate_msg": null,
        "urgent_expr": null,
        "regex_mask": null,
        "regex_valid": null,
        "required2": null,
        "warning_msg": null,
        "linked_question_num": null,
        "state_not_valid": null,
        "count_question_num": null,
        "isQuestionAllowed": true,
        "hasDerivedValue": false,
        "answers": [
            {
                "refNum": "3977344",
                "isRequired": false,
                "isValid": true,
                "isControlDisabled": null
            }
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "question_num": 20008050,
                "parent_num": 20008000,
                "order_num": 50,
                "control_type": "B",
                "question": "INSURANCE COMPANIES ARE REALLY PRECISE ON THIS ONE: Have you had a complete physical with your physician in the last 12 months which included a full blood workup?",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": "YesNo",
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": "*",
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": null,
                "summary_string": null,
                "insert_break": null,
                "req_children_num": null,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": true,
                        "isValid": false,
                        "isControlDisabled": null
                    }
                ],
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "question_num": 20008300,
                "parent_num": 20008000,
                "order_num": 300,
                "control_type": "B",
                "question": "Within the past 5 years, have you had any judgments, collections or liens filed against you?",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": "YesNo",
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": "*",
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": null,
                "summary_string": "/",
                "insert_break": null,
                "req_children_num": 1,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": true,
                        "isValid": false,
                        "isControlDisabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "question_num": 20008400,
                "parent_num": 20008000,
                "order_num": 400,
                "control_type": "B",
                "question": "In the past 5 years, have you ever requested or received a Worker's Compensation, Social Security or disability income payment, excluding a pregnancy related payment?",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": "YesNo",
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": "*",
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": null,
                "summary_string": null,
                "insert_break": null,
                "req_children_num": null,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": true,
                        "isValid": false,
                        "isControlDisabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "question_num": 20008600,
                "parent_num": 20008000,
                "order_num": 600,
                "control_type": "B",
                "question": "Are you considering using funds from your existing policies or contracts to pay premiums due on the new policy or contract?",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": "YesNo",
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": "*",
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": "450",
                "summary_string": "Using funds",
                "insert_break": null,
                "req_children_num": null,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": true,
                        "isValid": false,
                        "isControlDisabled": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "question_num": 20008601,
                "parent_num": 20008000,
                "order_num": 1100,
                "control_type": "S",
                "question": "Owner",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": null,
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": null,
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": null,
                "summary_string": null,
                "insert_break": 1,
                "req_children_num": null,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": false,
                        "isValid": true,
                        "isControlDisabled": null
                    }
                ],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "question_num": 20008610,
                        "parent_num": 20008601,
                        "order_num": 1110,
                        "control_type": "B",
                        "question": "Are you going to be the owner of this policy?",
                        "mask": null,
                        "keyword": null,
                        "description": "YesNo",
                        "enable": null,
                        "required": null,
                        "required1": "*",
                        "default_value": null,
                        "negative_value": null,
                        "summary_string": null,
                        "insert_break": null,
                        "req_children_num": null,
                        "urgent": null,
                        "validate_expr": null,
                        "validate_msg": null,
                        "urgent_expr": null,
                        "regex_mask": null,
                        "regex_valid": null,
                        "required2": null,
                        "warning_msg": null,
                        "linked_question_num": null,
                        "state_not_valid": null,
                        "count_question_num": null,
                        "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                        "hasDerivedValue": false,
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "refNum": "3977344",
                                "isRequired": true,
                                "isValid": false,
                                "isControlDisabled": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_num": 20020000,
        "parent_num": 20000000,
        "order_num": 10000,
        "control_type": "S",
        "question": "Generic At Apply",
        "mask": null,
        "keyword": null,
        "description": null,
        "enable": null,
        "required": null,
        "required1": null,
        "default_value": null,
        "negative_value": null,
        "summary_string": null,
        "insert_break": null,
        "req_children_num": null,
        "urgent": null,
        "validate_expr": null,
        "validate_msg": null,
        "urgent_expr": null,
        "regex_mask": null,
        "regex_valid": null,
        "required2": null,
        "warning_msg": null,
        "linked_question_num": null,
        "state_not_valid": null,
        "count_question_num": null,
        "isQuestionAllowed": true,
        "hasDerivedValue": false,
        "answers": [
            {
                "refNum": "3977344",
                "isRequired": false,
                "isValid": true,
                "isControlDisabled": null
            }
        ],
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "question_num": 19000000,
        "parent_num": 0,
        "order_num": 1010,
        "control_type": "S",
        "question": "Purpose Of Insurance",
        "mask": null,
        "keyword": null,
        "description": null,
        "enable": null,
        "required": null,
        "required1": null,
        "default_value": null,
        "negative_value": null,
        "summary_string": null,
        "insert_break": null,
        "req_children_num": null,
        "urgent": null,
        "validate_expr": null,
        "validate_msg": null,
        "urgent_expr": null,
        "regex_mask": null,
        "regex_valid": null,
        "required2": null,
        "warning_msg": null,
        "linked_question_num": null,
        "state_not_valid": null,
        "count_question_num": null,
        "isQuestionAllowed": true,
        "hasDerivedValue": false,
        "answers": [
            {
                "refNum": "3977344",
                "isRequired": false,
                "isValid": true,
                "isControlDisabled": null
            }
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "question_num": 19000400,
                "parent_num": 19000000,
                "order_num": 1040,
                "control_type": "C",
                "question": "Business Policy",
                "mask": null,
                "keyword": null,
                "description": null,
                "enable": null,
                "required": null,
                "required1": null,
                "default_value": null,
                "negative_value": null,
                "summary_string": "Business Policy",
                "insert_break": 1,
                "req_children_num": null,
                "urgent": null,
                "validate_expr": null,
                "validate_msg": null,
                "urgent_expr": null,
                "regex_mask": null,
                "regex_valid": null,
                "required2": null,
                "warning_msg": null,
                "linked_question_num": null,
                "state_not_valid": null,
                "count_question_num": null,
                "isQuestionAllowed": true,
                "hasDerivedValue": false,
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "refNum": "3977344",
                        "isRequired": false,
                        "isValid": true,
                        "isControlDisabled": null
                    }
                ],
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

my current code is

```
const getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree = questionTree => {
  let results = [];

  function getQuestionNum(questionTree) {
    for (let question of questionTree) {
      results.push(question.question_num);
      if (
        question.children &&
        Array.isArray(question.children) &&
        question.children.length > 0
      )
        getQuestionNum(question.children);
    }
  }

  getQuestionNum(questionTree);
  return results;
};
```

And it is giving desired output which is

```
[
  20008000, 20008050,
  20008300, 20008400,
  20008600, 20008601,
  20008610, 20020000,
  19000000, 19000400
]
```

just looking if I achieve same with array.reduce

Comment: Your original solution is very clear and readable. Do you *really* want to exchange it for a possibly-unreadable functional one?

Comment: You should try it first. Please don't ask SO to write code for you if you haven't tried it.  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

[`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) doesn't seem to be a good fit for this task, but here you go:

```js
function getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree) {
  const results = [];

  function getQuestionNum(questionTree) {
    // .reduce() takes in and returns a reference to 'results'.
    // It runs the callback 0 times if the array it was called on has a length of 0.
    return questionTree.reduce((results, question) => {

      // For each question, we push its number onto 'results'
      results.push(question.question_num);

      // ...then go to its '.children', fallback to an array if that's nullish.
      // The callback function *must* returns the accumulated value,
      // which, in this case, is 'results', for the later call to use.
      return getQuestionNum(question.children ?? []);
    }, results);
  }

  return getQuestionNum(questionTree);
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree) {
  const results = [];

  function getQuestionNum(questionTree) {
    return questionTree.reduce((results, question) => {
      results.push(question.question_num);
      return getQuestionNum(question.children ?? []);
    }, results);
  }

  return getQuestionNum(questionTree);
}

const questionTree = [
  {
    question_num: 20008000,
    parent_num: 20000000,
    order_num: 175,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'PACL',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: [
      {
        question_num: 20008050,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 50,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          'INSURANCE COMPANIES ARE REALLY PRECISE ON THIS ONE: Have you had a complete physical with your physician in the last 12 months which included a full blood workup?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008300,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 300,
        control_type: 'B',
        question: 'Within the past 5 years, have you had any judgments, collections or liens filed against you?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: '/',
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: 1,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: false
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008400,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 400,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          "In the past 5 years, have you ever requested or received a Worker's Compensation, Social Security or disability income payment, excluding a pregnancy related payment?",
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: false
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008600,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 600,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          'Are you considering using funds from your existing policies or contracts to pay premiums due on the new policy or contract?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: '450',
        summary_string: 'Using funds',
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008601,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 1100,
        control_type: 'S',
        question: 'Owner',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: null,
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: null,
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: 1,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: false,
            isValid: true,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: [
          {
            question_num: 20008610,
            parent_num: 20008601,
            order_num: 1110,
            control_type: 'B',
            question: 'Are you going to be the owner of this policy?',
            mask: null,
            keyword: null,
            description: 'YesNo',
            enable: null,
            required: null,
            required1: '*',
            default_value: null,
            negative_value: null,
            summary_string: null,
            insert_break: null,
            req_children_num: null,
            urgent: null,
            validate_expr: null,
            validate_msg: null,
            urgent_expr: null,
            regex_mask: null,
            regex_valid: null,
            required2: null,
            warning_msg: null,
            linked_question_num: null,
            state_not_valid: null,
            count_question_num: null,
            isQuestionAllowed: true,
            hasDerivedValue: false,
            answers: [
              {
                refNum: '3977344',
                isRequired: true,
                isValid: false,
                isControlDisabled: null
              }
            ],
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question_num: 20020000,
    parent_num: 20000000,
    order_num: 10000,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'Generic At Apply',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: []
  },
  {
    question_num: 19000000,
    parent_num: 0,
    order_num: 1010,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'Purpose Of Insurance',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: [
      {
        question_num: 19000400,
        parent_num: 19000000,
        order_num: 1040,
        control_type: 'C',
        question: 'Business Policy',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: null,
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: null,
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: 'Business Policy',
        insert_break: 1,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: false,
            isValid: true,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];


console.log(getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for a functional style:

```js
function getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree) {
  const results = [];

  // Declare a function and immediately call it
  (function getQuestionNum(questionTree) {

    // .forEach() doesn't return anything, so return is not needed.
    questionTree.forEach(question => {
      results.push(question.question_num);
      getQuestionNum(question.children ?? []);
    });
  })(questionTree);
  
  return results;
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree) {
  const results = [];

  (function getQuestionNum(questionTree) {
    questionTree.forEach(question => {
      results.push(question.question_num);
      getQuestionNum(question.children ?? []);
    });
  })(questionTree);
  
  return results;
}

const questionTree = [
  {
    question_num: 20008000,
    parent_num: 20000000,
    order_num: 175,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'PACL',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: [
      {
        question_num: 20008050,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 50,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          'INSURANCE COMPANIES ARE REALLY PRECISE ON THIS ONE: Have you had a complete physical with your physician in the last 12 months which included a full blood workup?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008300,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 300,
        control_type: 'B',
        question: 'Within the past 5 years, have you had any judgments, collections or liens filed against you?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: '/',
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: 1,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: false
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008400,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 400,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          "In the past 5 years, have you ever requested or received a Worker's Compensation, Social Security or disability income payment, excluding a pregnancy related payment?",
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: false
          }
        ],
        children: []
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008600,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 600,
        control_type: 'B',
        question:
          'Are you considering using funds from your existing policies or contracts to pay premiums due on the new policy or contract?',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: 'YesNo',
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: '*',
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: '450',
        summary_string: 'Using funds',
        insert_break: null,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: true,
            isValid: false,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question_num: 20008601,
        parent_num: 20008000,
        order_num: 1100,
        control_type: 'S',
        question: 'Owner',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: null,
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: null,
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: null,
        insert_break: 1,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: false,
            isValid: true,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: [
          {
            question_num: 20008610,
            parent_num: 20008601,
            order_num: 1110,
            control_type: 'B',
            question: 'Are you going to be the owner of this policy?',
            mask: null,
            keyword: null,
            description: 'YesNo',
            enable: null,
            required: null,
            required1: '*',
            default_value: null,
            negative_value: null,
            summary_string: null,
            insert_break: null,
            req_children_num: null,
            urgent: null,
            validate_expr: null,
            validate_msg: null,
            urgent_expr: null,
            regex_mask: null,
            regex_valid: null,
            required2: null,
            warning_msg: null,
            linked_question_num: null,
            state_not_valid: null,
            count_question_num: null,
            isQuestionAllowed: true,
            hasDerivedValue: false,
            answers: [
              {
                refNum: '3977344',
                isRequired: true,
                isValid: false,
                isControlDisabled: null
              }
            ],
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question_num: 20020000,
    parent_num: 20000000,
    order_num: 10000,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'Generic At Apply',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: []
  },
  {
    question_num: 19000000,
    parent_num: 0,
    order_num: 1010,
    control_type: 'S',
    question: 'Purpose Of Insurance',
    mask: null,
    keyword: null,
    description: null,
    enable: null,
    required: null,
    required1: null,
    default_value: null,
    negative_value: null,
    summary_string: null,
    insert_break: null,
    req_children_num: null,
    urgent: null,
    validate_expr: null,
    validate_msg: null,
    urgent_expr: null,
    regex_mask: null,
    regex_valid: null,
    required2: null,
    warning_msg: null,
    linked_question_num: null,
    state_not_valid: null,
    count_question_num: null,
    isQuestionAllowed: true,
    hasDerivedValue: false,
    answers: [
      {
        refNum: '3977344',
        isRequired: false,
        isValid: true,
        isControlDisabled: null
      }
    ],
    children: [
      {
        question_num: 19000400,
        parent_num: 19000000,
        order_num: 1040,
        control_type: 'C',
        question: 'Business Policy',
        mask: null,
        keyword: null,
        description: null,
        enable: null,
        required: null,
        required1: null,
        default_value: null,
        negative_value: null,
        summary_string: 'Business Policy',
        insert_break: 1,
        req_children_num: null,
        urgent: null,
        validate_expr: null,
        validate_msg: null,
        urgent_expr: null,
        regex_mask: null,
        regex_valid: null,
        required2: null,
        warning_msg: null,
        linked_question_num: null,
        state_not_valid: null,
        count_question_num: null,
        isQuestionAllowed: true,
        hasDerivedValue: false,
        answers: [
          {
            refNum: '3977344',
            isRequired: false,
            isValid: true,
            isControlDisabled: null
          }
        ],
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];


console.log(getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Both of these are not as clear (and, perhaps, as fast) as your original solution, so my recommendation is that you should just use yours.

Comment: You are misusing `reduce`. `reduce` callbacks should not modify variables from outer scopes. Delete your `const results ` and call `return getQuestionNum(questionTree, []);`

Comment: @RuanMendes It's there to reflect the symmetry between the two solutions and OP's. Also, that callbacks should not modify variables from outer scopes is more of a convention rather than a technical restriction.

Comment: It's surely not a technical restriction but it's bad practice, like relying on global variables. It's confusing! You are defining two variables with the same name in your two scopes. I'm just saying your code is hard to read and following the convention that callbacks of `Array.prototype` functions will make it much easier to maintain it.

Comment: @RuanMendes That they are unreadable and unmaintainable is exactly what I'm trying to highlight. Otherwise, the solution is already included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the comments, your `for...of` loop is clearer and probably more performant than an equivalent `reduce()`. There is no need for the nested function though, you can simply recurse on the outer function.

```js
const questionTree = [{ question_num: 20008000, parent_num: 20000000, order_num: 175, control_type: 'S', question: 'PACL', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 20008050, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 50, control_type: 'B', question: 'INSURANCE COMPANIES ARE REALLY PRECISE ON THIS ONE: Have you had a complete physical with your physician in the last 12 months which included a full blood workup?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008300, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 300, control_type: 'B', question: 'Within the past 5 years, have you had any judgments, collections or liens filed against you?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: '/', insert_break: null, req_children_num: 1, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: false, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008400, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 400, control_type: 'B', question: "In the past 5 years, have you ever requested or received a Worker's Compensation, Social Security or disability income payment, excluding a pregnancy related payment?", mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: false, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008600, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 600, control_type: 'B', question: 'Are you considering using funds from your existing policies or contracts to pay premiums due on the new policy or contract?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: '450', summary_string: 'Using funds', insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], }, { question_num: 20008601, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 1100, control_type: 'S', question: 'Owner', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: 1, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 20008610, parent_num: 20008601, order_num: 1110, control_type: 'B', question: 'Are you going to be the owner of this policy?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], },], },], }, { question_num: 20020000, parent_num: 20000000, order_num: 10000, control_type: 'S', question: 'Generic At Apply', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 19000000, parent_num: 0, order_num: 1010, control_type: 'S', question: 'Purpose Of Insurance', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 19000400, parent_num: 19000000, order_num: 1040, control_type: 'C', question: 'Business Policy', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: 'Business Policy', insert_break: 1, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], },], },];

function getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree) {
  let results = [];

  for (const question of questionTree) {
    results.push(
      question.question_num,
      ...getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(question.children ?? [])
    );
  }

  return results;
}

console.log(getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree));
```

---

If you do want to use an Array method then [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is probably the most directly applicable.

```js
const questionTree = [{ question_num: 20008000, parent_num: 20000000, order_num: 175, control_type: 'S', question: 'PACL', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 20008050, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 50, control_type: 'B', question: 'INSURANCE COMPANIES ARE REALLY PRECISE ON THIS ONE: Have you had a complete physical with your physician in the last 12 months which included a full blood workup?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008300, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 300, control_type: 'B', question: 'Within the past 5 years, have you had any judgments, collections or liens filed against you?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: '/', insert_break: null, req_children_num: 1, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: false, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008400, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 400, control_type: 'B', question: "In the past 5 years, have you ever requested or received a Worker's Compensation, Social Security or disability income payment, excluding a pregnancy related payment?", mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: false, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 20008600, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 600, control_type: 'B', question: 'Are you considering using funds from your existing policies or contracts to pay premiums due on the new policy or contract?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: '450', summary_string: 'Using funds', insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], }, { question_num: 20008601, parent_num: 20008000, order_num: 1100, control_type: 'S', question: 'Owner', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: 1, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 20008610, parent_num: 20008601, order_num: 1110, control_type: 'B', question: 'Are you going to be the owner of this policy?', mask: null, keyword: null, description: 'YesNo', enable: null, required: null, required1: '*', default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: true, isValid: false, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], },], },], }, { question_num: 20020000, parent_num: 20000000, order_num: 10000, control_type: 'S', question: 'Generic At Apply', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], }, { question_num: 19000000, parent_num: 0, order_num: 1010, control_type: 'S', question: 'Purpose Of Insurance', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: null, insert_break: null, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [{ question_num: 19000400, parent_num: 19000000, order_num: 1040, control_type: 'C', question: 'Business Policy', mask: null, keyword: null, description: null, enable: null, required: null, required1: null, default_value: null, negative_value: null, summary_string: 'Business Policy', insert_break: 1, req_children_num: null, urgent: null, validate_expr: null, validate_msg: null, urgent_expr: null, regex_mask: null, regex_valid: null, required2: null, warning_msg: null, linked_question_num: null, state_not_valid: null, count_question_num: null, isQuestionAllowed: true, hasDerivedValue: false, answers: [{ refNum: '3977344', isRequired: false, isValid: true, isControlDisabled: null, },], children: [], },], },];

const getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree = (questionTree) =>
  questionTree.flatMap((question) => [
    question.question_num,
    ...getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(question.children ?? []),
  ]);

console.log(getQuestionNumbersFromQuestionTree(questionTree));
```